# Sessions in Laravel 5 and 4.2

Tags: php, session, laravel

I'm a bit confused about the use of sessions in Laravel 4.2 to 5.1. The confusion is when we use core PHP, we use sessions array from page to page navigation of a registered and logged in user like this:

```
session_start(); // to start session
session_end(); // ends the session
echo $_SESSION['username']; // to get user name
if(session set for a specific user) then show his dashboard/profile page
```

How we can use sessions like the above or plz explain how Laravel eliminate the need to use sessions in this way and introduced any other way if any.

But when we use Laravel, how can we achieve all that page to page navigation and keep track of the user at page b who is coming from page a? If there is no need to use sessions array at all? What actually Laravel provide the solution???

Comment: There is an entire section in the docs recommending how to use sessions in Laravel.  http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store session data by including `use Session;` at the top of your controller

Save data to session:
    `Session::put('option', '$option');`

Retrieve data:
    `$option = Session::get('option');`

Answer (score 3):

You can also save session via global session helper like this.

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

You can retrieve the value of session at any page using this.

```
$value = session('key');
```

If you would like to remove all data from the session, you may use the flush() method.

```
session()->flush();
```